# How to get device specifies for android_config_files

Tags: android, performance, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I am trying to update device specifications in `android_config_files.xml` but unable to find how to get or generate these tags.. please help

```
<mb520>
   <support_status val="um2=s;um2i=s;shuttle=s;unipay=s"> </support_status>
   <directionOutputWave>1</directionOutputWave>
   <InputFreq>32000</InputFreq>
   <OutputFreq>24000</OutputFreq>
   <WaveDirct>1</WaveDirct>
   <_Low>-10800</_Low>
   <_High>10800</_High>
   <__Low>-5400</__Low>
   <__High>5400</__High>
   <highThreshold>15000</highThreshold>
   <lowThreshold>-15000</lowThreshold>
   <device_Apm_Base>30000</device_Apm_Base>
   <min>1</min>
   <max>10</max>
   <baudRate>4800</baudRate>
   <preAmbleFactor>10</preAmbleFactor>
</mb520>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess it is card reader or something like that. I have the same problems, and I would suggest you to contact with manufacturer and ask for specs. Other than that,

```
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        String rate = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
        String size = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);



        Log.d("Buffer Size and sample rate", "Size :" + size + " & Rate: " + rate );
```

Sample rate and buffer size can be captured like this. Note that valid for API >17
For other params, I cant really help.